# Why is the "Learn More" link not linking to the page?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to understand how this code (from another developer) is written. It has a bug but I can't seem to fix it. The learn more link doesn't link to the post in the custom field.

I've tried to remove the learn more lines but it then it changes the slide link to link to the image itself and not what's present in the custom link field.

```
$slides = ONS_Slide_Custom_Post_Type::find_all('DESC');
if (isset($slides) && count($slides > 0)) {
    $items = array();
    foreach ($slides as $slide) {
        //echo '<tt><pre>' . var_export($slide, true) . '</pre></tt>';
        $item = new stdClass();
        if (isset($slide->custom_data) && count($slide->custom_data) > 0) {
            if (isset($slide->custom_data['ons_slide_image'])) {
                $item->src = $slide->custom_data['ons_slide_image'];
            }
            if (isset($slide->custom_data['ons_slide_heading'])) {
                $item->heading = $slide->custom_data['ons_slide_heading'];
                $item->heading .= '<span class="punctuation">.</span><span class="learn_more">&nbsp;&raquo;</span>';
            }
            if (isset($slide->custom_data['ons_slide_caption'])) {
                $item->caption = $slide->custom_data['ons_slide_caption'];
                $item->caption .= '&nbsp;<a href="#" class="learn_more">Learn more &raquo;</a>';

            }
            if (isset($slide->custom_data['ons_slide_href'])) {
                $item->href = $slide->custom_data['ons_slide_href'];

            } else {
                $item->href = "#";
            }
        }
        $items[] = $item;
    }
    $carousel = new ONS_Bootstrap_Carousel($items);
    echo $carousel;
}
```

Comment: That is because `<a href="#">` change to `<a href="ARTICLE URL">`

Comment: that "ARTICLE URL" should be dynamically populated by the custom_data field 'ons_slide_href'

Comment: Right, so do that then

Comment: It seems this line `$item->href = $slide->custom_data['ons_slide_href'];` should be injecting the URL into the slide. Find the code that populates that array, learn how it works, and fix whatever needs fixing so it does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @cabrerahector I updated the post to include a class I found in a separate file. The code I attached is the entire code for that newly found file. Do you see anything here that may be causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing something with `$slide->custom_data['ons_slide_href'];` but AFTER the lines of code that are outputting your anchor tag.

So try switching the processing about a bit like this

```
$slides = ONS_Slide_Custom_Post_Type::find_all('DESC');
if (isset($slides) && count($slides > 0)) {
    $items = array();
    foreach ($slides as $slide) {
        //echo '<tt><pre>' . var_export($slide, true) . '</pre></tt>';
        $item = new stdClass();
        if (isset($slide->custom_data) && count($slide->custom_data) > 0) {
            if (isset($slide->custom_data['ons_slide_image'])) {
                $item->src = $slide->custom_data['ons_slide_image'];
            }
            if (isset($slide->custom_data['ons_slide_heading'])) {
                $item->heading = $slide->custom_data['ons_slide_heading'];
                $item->heading .= '<span class="punctuation">.</span><span class="learn_more">&nbsp;&raquo;</span>';
            }

        // moved this code above the anchor tag line
            if (isset($slide->custom_data['ons_slide_href'])) {
                $item->href = $slide->custom_data['ons_slide_href'];
            } else {
                $item->href = "#";
            }

        // Now concatenate $item->href in the anchor tag line
            if (isset($slide->custom_data['ons_slide_caption'])) {
                $item->caption = $slide->custom_data['ons_slide_caption'];
                $item->caption .= '&nbsp;<a href="' . $item->href . '" class="learn_more">Learn more &raquo;</a>';

            }
        }

        $items[] = $item;
    }
    $carousel = new ONS_Bootstrap_Carousel($items);
    echo $carousel;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. This worked like a charm. @RiggsFolly could you explain why this post was down voted? Sorry I'm new to posting but I'd love to contribute to the community. Maybe I just don't know the etiquette yet?

Comment: Hi, probably because it looks pretty much like a TYPO i.e. the code was all there but in the wrong order, and a simple eyeball noticed that there was only a `#` in the href attribute. But you can never be totally sure, some people DV without any explanation

Comment: But the **good news** Some people UpVote for no apparent reason as well :)